How do I turn a Sync XState to Async using React
I have something like this working
const getItems = () => {
    return [{
        name: "test item"
    }];
};
export const simpleMachine = createMachine({
  id: 'simple',
  context: {
    items: []
  },
  on: {
    GET: {
      actions: assign({
        items: () =>{
          return getItems();
        }
      })
    },

This works fine but now I want to try and make it asyc so I change to
const getItems = async () => {
    return [{
        name: "test item"
    }];
};

export const simpleMachine = setup({
    actors: {
        getItems
    }
}).createMachine({
    id: 'simple',
    initial: 'idle',
    context: {
        items: []
    },
    states: {
        idle: {
            on: {
                GET: 'loading'
            }
        },
        loading: {
            invoke:{
                src: 'getItems',
                onDone: {
                    target: "idle",
                    actions: assign({
                        output: (_, event) => event.data,
                    })
                },
                onError: {
                    target: 'idle',
                    actions: assign({
                        items: () => []
                    })
                }
            }

both are called using
useEffect(() => {
        send({ type: 'GET' });
    }, [send]);

But my breakpoint in the getItems never gets hit and the items are not added to the context. What am I missing how do I get the async to work like the sync?
Update
I tried adding an entry log...
idle: {
  entry: ()=>{
    console.log("Entering")
  },
  on: {
    GET: 'loading'
  }
},

and I do see the Entering message so it is getting to the state but not into loading.

Unsurprisingly there were a few issues but to TLDR here is the corrected version
const getItems = fromPromise(async () => {
    return [{ name: "test item" }];
});

export const simpleMachine = createMachine({
    initial: 'idle',
    context: { items: [] },
    states: {
        idle: {
            on: { GET: 'loading' }
        },
        loading: {
            invoke: {
                src: getItems,
                onDone: {
                    target: "idle",
                    actions: ({ context, event }) => context.items = event.output
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
export const ActorContext = createContext(null);
export function AppProvider({ children }) {
    const [state, send] = useMachine(simpleMachine);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Sending GET event");
        send({type: 'GET'});
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Current state:", state.value);
    }, [state.value]);
    return (
        <ActorContext.Provider value={{state, send}}>
            {children}
        </ActorContext.Provider>
    );
}
function App() {
    return (
        <AppProvider>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <TestComponent />
        </AppProvider>
    )
}

export default App

These seems to have been a couple of issues but the main one was

event.output should be used with async instead of event.data

Here is the AI output for more info
Key changes:

Use fromPromise to wrap async functions
Access promise data via event.output instead of event.data
Direct context mutation instead of assign helper
No need for setup()/actors configuration

